# Format current date and time in VBScript

Tags: datetime, vbscript, asp-classic

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I'm very new at ASP I want to format the current date and time as follows:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

But all i can do is the following

```vb
Response.Write Date
```

Can someone help me out please.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Date formatting options are limited in Classic ASP by default, there is a function `FormatDateTime()` which can format your date is various ways based on the servers regional settings.

For more control over date formatting though there are built in date time functions

- `Year(date)` - *Returns a whole number representing the year. Passing `Date()` will give back the current year.*
- `Month(date)` - *Returns a whole number between 1 and 12, inclusive, representing the month of the year. Passing `Date()` will return the current month of the year.*
- `MonthName(month[, abbv])` - *Returns a string indicating the specified month. Passing in `Month(Date())` as the month will give back the current Month string. **As suggested by [@Martha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121333/martha)***
- `Day(date)` - *Returns a whole number between 1 and 31, inclusive, representing the day of the month. Passing `Date()` will return the current day of the month.*
- `Hour(time)` - *Returns a whole number between 0 and 23, inclusive, representing the hour of the day. Passing `Time()` will return the current hour.*
- `Minute(time)` - *Returns a whole number between 0 and 59, inclusive, representing the minute of the hour. Passing `Time()` will return the current minute.*
- `Second(time)` - *Returns a whole number between 0 and 59, inclusive, representing the second of the minute. Passing `Time()` will return the current second.*

> **IMPORTANT:**
> When formatting date / time values, **always** store the date / time value first. Also, any needed calculations *(`DateAdd()` etc.)* should be applied before attempting to format or you will get unexpected results.

The functions `Month()`, `Day()`, `Hour()`, `Minute()` and `Second()` all return whole numbers. Luckily there is an easy workaround that lets you pad these values quickly `Right("00" & value, 2)` what it does is append `00` to the front of the value then from the right take the first two characters. This ensures that all single digit values return prefixed with a `0`.

```vb
Dim dd, mm, yy, hh, nn, ss
Dim datevalue, timevalue, dtsnow, dtsvalue

'Store DateTimeStamp once.
dtsnow = Now()

'Individual date components
dd = Right("00" & Day(dtsnow), 2)
mm = Right("00" & Month(dtsnow), 2)
yy = Year(dtsnow)
hh = Right("00" & Hour(dtsnow), 2)
nn = Right("00" & Minute(dtsnow), 2)
ss = Right("00" & Second(dtsnow), 2)

'Build the date string in the format yyyy-mm-dd
datevalue = yy & "-" & mm & "-" & dd
'Build the time string in the format hh:mm:ss
timevalue = hh & ":" & nn & ":" & ss
'Concatenate both together to build the timestamp yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
dtsvalue = datevalue & " " & timevalue

Call Response.Write(dtsvalue)
```

**Note:** *You can build the date string in one call but decided to break it down into the three variables to make it easier to read.*

---

- [How Can I Format Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003923/vbscript-how-can-i-format-date)
- [Example of Parsing a Date String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48243660/692942) *(Answers provide approaches to taking a date string format and parsing it to a valid `Date` variable)*.
- [Format the date of the previous day format yyyymmdd with VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56835958/692942)  *(Example of why storing date / time before performing formatting is important)*
- [VBScript ISO8601](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6900298/692942) *(Example of functions to construct an ISO 8601 compliant date string)*

Comment: The OP doesn't appear to need it, but there's also the MonthName(mm,abbr) function - mm is the month number, and abbr is a boolean indicating whether to abbreviate the month name or not.

Comment: @Martha Yeah, didn't include it as it wasn't relevant to the date format the OP wanted to achieve.

Comment: You can simplify more, instead format_zeros use this other format: right("00" & month(date()),2) same format for day and year

Comment: @Mastercafe That is also true.

Comment: @ Lankymart you should use the shortcut you provided to me to revise your answer here like, tmp = Right("00" & Hour(Time()), 2).  Couldn't you dump the format_zeros() function then? I appreciate you letting some of us others answer questions when I'm sure you could easily.

Comment: @Jake Yeah I need to go back and revise this answer.

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how ridiculous complex and faffy VBScript can manage to make even the simplest of tasks that can be accomplished with half a line of code in any sane language…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet is a scripting language that is over 20 years old.

Comment: Why does the padding need **2** zero's (as in `Right("00" & Day(dtsnow), 2)` - surely **one** zero should be enough, seen as at minimum, the day,month,hour etc will have one digit: `Right("0" & Day(dtsnow), 2)` ?

Comment: @kneidels In that scenario `00` isn’t required but if I was passing a variable in (not `Day(dtsnow)`) and it’s value was null or empty I'd want it to default to `00`.