# I need to convert PHP date('Y-m-d H:i:s P'); to asp classic

Tags: php, asp-classic, date-formatting

Can anyone help me with this conversion? I am not an asp classic developer so simplest method would work best.

I need to have the date formatted as 2014-04-09 12:12:52 -01:00

In PHP i can do it using date('Y-m-d H:i:s P');

Any ideas?

Comment: your date function has same output as you required

Comment: @SohailYasmin He's asking how to display the date in that format in [tag:asp-classic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (but see "Slight Caveat" at the bottom of the answer);

```vb
'Function used to pad numeric values, i.e 1 to 01
'i_zeros - Number of zero's to prefix the s_value with.
Function format_zeros(s_value,i_zeros)
  If Len(s_value) < i_zeros Then
    Do Until Len(s_value) = i_zeros
      s_value = "0" & s_value
    Loop
  End If
  format_zeros = s_value
End Function

Dim somedate, sometime, somedatetimestamp

'Build the date string in the format yyyy-mm-dd
somedate = Year(Date()) & "-" & format_zeros(Month(Date()), 2) & "-" & format_zeros(Day(Date()), 2)
'Build the time string in the format hh:mm:ss
sometime = format_zeros(Hour(Time()), 2) & ":" & format_zeros(Minute(Time()), 2) & ":" & format_zeros(Second(Time()), 2)
'Concatenate both together to build the timestamp yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
somedatetimestamp = somedate & " " & sometime

Call Response.Write(somedatetimestamp)
```

> **NOTE:**
>
> I've already written an [extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942) that addresses date formatting here and explains the various functions available to help you build custom formats.

**Slight Caveat**

Not sure how to best approach the timezone offset but there is some decent articles like [this one](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/date-time-routines-manipulation/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-gmt-time.html) that explain conversion between timezones.

If you're dealing with `-0100` timezone offset exclusively you can just append it to your string something like;

```vb
somedatetimestamp = somedatetimestamp & " -0100"
```

As for conversion to and from a timezone that can be decidedly trickier.