# Classic ASP: Get datetime from string?

Tags: html, string, datetime, asp-classic

I have a problem. I'm coding classic asp at the moment and I need to get dateTime out of string and changes its' format to short dateTime and put it in the same place again. (I hope this is somehow possible even)

My code looks like this:

```
<tr>
<th>Nuorisokoulutus</th>
<th colspan='1'>Järjestäjä</th>
<th style='padding-right:5;'>Vuosi</th>
<th style='padding-right:5;'>Massaajo</th>
<th colspan='4'>PVM</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='40%'>Varhaisnuorten ohjaajakurssi</td>
<td width='40%'>Spek</td>
<td style='padding-right:5;'>2014</td>
<td style='text-align:center; padding-right:5;'><img style='width:15px;' src='images/check-small-approved.png'></td>
<td colspan='4' style='padding-right:5;'>28.7.2014 12:37:07</td>
<td><a href='jaskoulutus.asp?id=742&delete=101107'>Poista</a></td>
</tr>
```

In the last lines there's the dateTime which comes from dataBase table to this html. I can't change the format of the dateTime from dataBase because it is used in another place as in long dateTime but in this html I need the shorter one. Is there a way to get that date from html string and change it right there to short one or what should I do?

For now I have tried Split and InStr functions but I don't get good results with them...

Comment: You're not showing the code just the resultant HTML, can you post the classic asp code that produces this fragment?

Comment: When it comes to formatting dates in classic asp you might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942) useful.

Comment: thanks, I'll check if I can use some of those

Comment: If you post the code we would be able to provide a more tailored solution but link covers most formatting situations.