# niceLabel VBscript reformat date

Tags: date, vbscript, date-formatting

New to both NiceLabel and VBScript. I have an expiration date string which requires leading zero's when necessary.

For example;

```
"2016-2-7" to "2016-02-07"
"2016-2-27" to "2016-02-27"
```

I'm guessing the best way is to:

1. Determine the number of digits (`n`) in the value (`v`) via string conversion and length method
2. `if n &lt; 2: v = "0"+ v;`

however I cannot figure out how to do this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is VBScript then just break it up and pad it.

```
Dim LabelDate, FormattedDate

LabelDate = #2/7/2016#
FormattedDate = Right("00" & DatePart("d", LabelDate), 2) & "-" & _
                Right("00" & DatePart("m", LabelDate), 2) & "-" & _
                DatePart("yyyy", LabelDate)

'Test conversion
Call MsgBox(LabelDate & " to " & FormattedDate)
```

If you really want to break it down, you can do;

```
Dim LabelDate, FormattedDate
Dim LabelMonth, LabelMonth, LabelYear

LabelDate = #2/7/2016#
LabelYear = DatePart("yyyy", LabelDate)
LabelMonth = Right("00" & DatePart("m", LabelDate), 2)
LabelDay = Right("00" & DatePart("d", LabelDate), 2)

'Restructure them how you want...
FormattedDate =  LabelDay & "-" & LabelMonth & "-" LabelYear         

'Test conversion
Call MsgBox(LabelDate & " to " & FormattedDate)
```

Yet another approach to make the restructure a bit nicer is to use an `Array()`.

```
Dim LabelDate, FormattedDate
Dim LabelDateArray

LabelDate = #2/7/2016#
LabelDateArray = Array( _
                   Right("00" & DatePart("d", LabelDate), 2), _
                   Right("00" & DatePart("m", LabelDate), 2), _
                   DatePart("yyyy", LabelDate) _
                 )

'Restructure using the Array...
FormattedDate = Join(LabelDateArray, "-")        

'Test conversion
Call MsgBox(LabelDate & " to " & FormattedDate)
```

#### Just to explain what's going on

In the end you are wanting to take a date literal and format it for display purposes. Padding is actually simpler then it first appears, all you need to do is pre-append `"00"` to the front of the value then append the specific `DatePart()` *(only needed for `Month` and `Day`)*. Then you use a simple hack to get the desired result using the `Right()` function we take 2 characters from the left, which if you value is 1 character applies the `"0"` padding.

#### Apparently it takes another answer to point out this out

Hardly relevant but as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35062134/692942) highlights, you can also use

1. `Month(LabelDate)` instead of `DatePart("m", LabelDate)`
2. `Day(LabelDate)` instead of `DatePart("d", LabelDate)`

Both functions do the same thing and I don't know of any overriding reason to use one or the other, except maybe `Month(LabelDate)` is shorter to write then `DatePart("d", LabelDate)`. The above method will work using either so it's negligible.

#### Why do some examples use `Right("0" &` not `Right("00" &` instead?

It's simple, they are assuming you will always have a value for the `Month` and `Day` but as I have had in the past you won't always pass those values in from system functions, so for the occasions where a `null` value is passed it will ensure that the date part is set to `00`.

> Also it worth pointing out that what all these solutions produce is a string it's no longer a date so if you are going to perform date functions against it make sure, you either store the original value and use that or use `CDate()` to convert the value to a valid date literal.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Format current date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942) - *Information on building formatted date strings in Classic ASP / VBScript*

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the month using the `Month` function (or the day using the `Day` function).
2. Prepend a `0` to the result.
3. Use the `Right` function to extract the last two characters.

If the month is `2`, this will prepend `0` to give `02`. Taking the two right-most characters will result in `02`.

If the month is `12`, you get `012`, and the two right-most characters are `12`.

Below is an example.

```
MyDate = #2016-2-27#
MyMonth = Right("0" & Month(MyDate), 2)
MyDay = Right("0" & Day(MyDate), 2)
FormattedDate = Year(MyDate) & "-" & MyMonth & "-" & MyDay
MsgBox FormattedDate
```

Comment: How is this different to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35060805/692942)?

Comment: The separator I just notice was different, wow took a whole answer to just place that in a comment and I would have corrected the answer.

Comment: Btw `Right("0" & ` is fine if you the value you are checking always exists, reason I use `Right"00" & ` to accommodate null values.

Comment: @Lankymart I was typing my answer and submitted before I saw yours. The code in your original answer didn't work, so I left mine.

Comment: Yes, my code sample assumes a valid date to begin with. Whether you add `0` or `00` to the beginning, you'll have to add some error-handling either to ensure you're starting with a valid date or to check the output. What do you do if the month or day returns `00`?

Comment: It's not just `Date` values it's useful for `Time` as well.