# Classic ASP return dd/mm/yyyy when append with string

Tags: date, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-8

Please see the issue details and share the solution if you have. Thank you in advance.
Issue: Windows 2012/IIS 8.5 Classic ASP date format changing when we append with string. For example, date value 01/12/2016 (Jan 12th 2016) have been changed to 12/01/2016 (Dec 1st 2016) if we append with the string.

Source Code: (date.asp)

```
<%
Dim fordate
Dim fdate
fordate = Request.QueryString("fordate")
Response.Write(fordate)
fdate = cdate(fordate)
Response.Write(fdate)
Dim strsql
strsql = "exec testsp " & fdate
Response.Write(strsql)
%>
```

[image: Please see the output]

Comment: You have two servers with different system date formatting set, check the regional settings in the Control Panel on each server. This has nothing to do with IIS when a date is converted it becomes *"A String containing a date in the short-date format of your system"*. You can use [`FormatDateTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aebkz6s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which gives you some control over this but anything more then that you need to build the date format yourself. See [Format current date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format current date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574092/format-current-date-and-time)

Comment: did any of the suggestions help?

Answer (score 1):

When casting Date / Time to a String in VBScript the following applies

> *<sup>Quote from [MSDN - VBScript Reference - CStr Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk841e9(v=vs.84).aspx)</sup>*
> A String containing a date in the short-date format of your system

The effect by default whatever the *"short-date"* format settings are for dates values on the system<sup>#</sup> *(usually found under `Control Panel -> Language` but varies by OS)* is used when displaying String representations of date values in VBScript.

<sup># - By "System" we mean the Server / Computer whether it be in a client / server side environment.</sup>

---

#### Useful Links

- [Format current date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942)