# Server date and IIS date format different

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

The server where I publish my Website, the format is M/d/yyyy (eg: 2/25/2016)

But in the website, the date format is d/M/yyyy (eg: 25/2/2016). I want the date format in the website to be M/d/yyyy (like the server format).

```
Date: <%=now()%>
```

in .asp page, above code will return current date with d/M/yyyy.
I checked a few questions here in stackoverflow but none of them provided a solution for me. I changed the server date format, still no change. I change the culture setting in web.config (see code below) and restarted the IIS service and the server twice. Also the date still in d/M/yyyy format.

```xml
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file `GLOBAL.ASA`, in `Sub Session_OnStart`, put `Session.LCID = 1033`

List of LocaleID could be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx

Date format will be: 8/2/2016 11:16:18 AM

Answer (score 0):

The functions `Date()` and `Now()` in VBScript are controlled but the regional settings defined on the server they are running. Looking at the documentation it's quite clear:

> <sup>From [VBScript Language Reference - Now Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w568awd(v=vs.84).aspx)</sup>
>   *Returns the current date and time **according to the setting of your computer's system date and time**.*

Also for future reference the [`globalization` config section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.85).aspx) is directly related to ASP.Net and not Classic ASP. Setting the value of the `globalization` config section will have no effect on a Classic ASP Web Application.

You however have options for controlling the string representation of a date / time value in VBScript, which is already detailed here - [Format current date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942).

Or as [@Zam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3111800/zam) has [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38715041/692942) you do have some minor control of the format by using the

```
Session.LCID = 1033
```

Bear in mind that this will change the entire locale to en-US *(which I assume is what you are trying to do with the `globalization` settings in `web.config`)*.