# VB Script ReportBuilder 3.0 Convert String Date to YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: reporting-services, vbscript, reportbuilder3.0

I am creating a cube report using Report Builder but I need to convert the date string so it can sort properly.

Currently the date appears like this "Fri, Apr 13th, 2012" and I need it too look like 2012-04-13 so that it will sort properly.

Can I do both the string formatting and sorting under the Tablix Properties - Sort ?

Comment: Can you show us the raw data from your DataSet? Are the date values just strings, or actual dates which are just displaying in a format you don't want?

Comment: The date value is a created cube Dimension and when I mouse over the example date it shows [Date].[Date].[20120413] Member: Fri, Apr 13th, 2012,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to sort by the same format that is displayed in the report. You can either do the sorting in the SQL beforehand or you can sort at the dataset, table, or group level in the report. If the column is a `date` datatype, you can simply sort by it. As far as the formatting is concerned, if you right-click on the textbox and go to properties, you will see the date formatting options.