# Comparing DateFormat with Date String

Tags: xml, vbscript, hp-uft

I have a Date = "20180719" which I am taking out from XML file. I have a drop down field 'Manufacturing Date'(Windows application) which has format "**YYYYMMDD**".

Now I have to validate whether the '**Date**' is in the correct **Date Format** as provided in 'Manufacturing Date'.

Is there any function in which I can convert Date into DateFormat ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format current date and time in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574092/format-current-date-and-time-in-vbscript)

Comment: Obviously there is a difference between "Does this **string** adhere to the YYYYMMDD format?" and "How do I format a **date** according to YYYYMMDD?".

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner read the full question - *"Is there any function in which I can convert Date into DateFormat ?"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XML file should have a schema for validation, so that badly formatted dates (strings!) could be caught.
If your XML can contain surprises, you have to check the plausibility of the year/month/day-parts. In code:

```
Dim aT : aT = Split("20180719 19072018 07192018 20181212 20181313 11112233 33331122")
Dim sD
For Each sD in aT
    WScript.Echo sD, verdict(sD)
Next

' "YYYYMMDD" format hard coded, using DateSerial to check the plausibility of the y-m-d-parts
Function verdict(sD)
  verdict = "invalid"
  If 8 = Len(sD) Then
     Dim nY : nY = CInt(Left(sD, 4))
     Dim nM : nM = CInt(Mid(sD, 5, 2))
     Dim nD : nD = CInt(Right(sD, 2))
     Dim dD : dD = DateSerial(nY, nM, nD)
     If sD = Year(dD) & Right(100 + Month(dD), 2) & Right( 100 + Day(dD), 2) Then verdict = "ok"
  End If
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 51613138.vbs
20180719 ok
19072018 invalid
07192018 invalid
20181212 ok
20181313 invalid
11112233 invalid
33331122 ok
```

In addition, you may range check the year (using the numerical nY variable). Some border cases (Did the author of "20180102" want to specify a day in januar or february?) can't be decided, however.