# Format the date of the previous day format yyyymmdd with VBScript

Tags: date, vbscript, format

I need format the date of the previous day in this format, with **VBScript** :

> yyyymmdd

And I have tried this solution :

```
NewData = Right(Year(DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1)),4) &_
          Right(String(2, "0") &_
          Month(DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1)), 2) &_
          Right(String(2, "0") &_
          Day(DateAdd("d",-1, Now())), 2)
```

But instead of getting :

> 20190630

I have :

> 20190730

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not sure if this should be closed as a duplicate. OP wasn't having issues with the formatting part, but only with the "previous day" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first store yesterday in a variable and then do your formatting magic on this date.

```
dim yesterday
yesterday = DateAdd("d",-1, Now())
NewData = Right(Year(DateSerial(Year(yesterday),Month(yesterday),1)),4) _
        & Right(String(2, "0") _
        & Month(DateSerial(Year(yesterday),Month(yesterday),1)), 2) _
        & Right(String(2, "0") & Day(yesterday), 2)
```

I strongly suspect there are more straightforward ways to get a date in format YYYYMMDD however.

Comment: @Cid Thanks. I'v been switching syntaxis too much I'm afraid.