# 800A000D Format missmatch (VBS)

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a script in vbscript, and I got this error:

800A000D Format mismatch:

This is the code:

```
Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://OU=Usuarios,OU=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=uru,DC=zzz")

objOU.Filter = Array("group")

Dim ts, fso, parentFolder, folder, folderDirectory
    ts = CStr(Format(Now(),"#dd-mm-yyyy#")) 
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    folderDirectory = parentFolder & ts

Dim outputFileName
    outputFileName = ts & ".csv"

set outputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(outputFileName, TRUE)
For Each objGroup In objOU
  If InStr(1, objGroup.cn, "MIS_") = 1 Then
      For Each objMember In objGroup.Members
        outputFile.WriteLine objGroup.cn & ";" & objMember.sAMAccountName & ";" & objMember.displayname
      Next
  End If
Next
```

Thanks!

Comment: Plenty of information here about [formatting dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the function `Format`, which is not known by VBScript.

You can use `FormatDateTime` instead, but with limited formatting: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_formatdatetime.asp

Tip: Don't use `Now()` but `Date()` to avoid it outputs the time part too.

To gain your requested format you could try to use one of the defined formats of `FormatDateTime` and exchange `.` by `-` by using the `Replace` function.

If none fits you would have to create your own function which then splits the date into separate values for

- year: `Year(Date())`
- month: `Month(Date())`
- day: `Day(Date())`

and concatenates them as you want/need.

Comment: Thanks! this worked! Later I post the final code of the script!

Comment: I think I´ve done it, I´m a new participant, before I just consulted other ppl´s posts. Thanks!