# VBS Object Required Error manipulating strings

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am trying to create a simple script that prompts the user for their birthday, formatted as `10.02.20`, then takes that string and turns it into text, such as October 2nd 2020. I have the following code:

```
Dim bd, message, title ' define variables
title = "What is your birthday?" ' set variable
message = "Format like so: 12.15.07; 3.03.05" ' set variable

bd = InputBox(message, title) ' prompt user

Dim year
year = bd.Substring(6, 2)
Dim month
month = bd.Substring(0, 2)
Dim day
day = bd.Substring(3, 2)

msgbox bd ' for testing
call msgbox(year + month + day) 'also testing
```

And I am getting an error after the prompt, `...\Desktop\test.vbs(8, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: '12.23.03'` and I am not sure what it means, Object Required.

Any fixes or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format current date and time in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574092/format-current-date-and-time-in-vbscript)

Comment: `SubString()` is not supported you should use `Mid()`.

Comment: The error is because you try to call a method `SubString()` on a variable that isn’t an object reference as it wasn’t instantiated with `Set bd = ...` hence `Object required`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Substring` in VBScript. You can use [Mid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function) instead:

```
Dim year
year = Mid(bd, 7, 2)
```

The first character in a string is at position 1, not 0, so I adjusted your parameter from 6 to 7.

Also, to concatenate strings, although `+` works, you can also use `&`:

```
call msgbox(year & month & day)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function in vbscript : `FormatDateTime(date,format)`

Parameter   Description
date    Required.

Any valid date expression (like `Date()` or `Now()`)
format  Optional.

A value that specifies the date/time format to use can take the following values:

```
0 = vbGeneralDate - Default. Returns date: mm/dd/yyyy and time if specified: hh:mm:ss PM/AM.
1 = vbLongDate - Returns date: weekday, monthname, year
2 = vbShortDate - Returns date: mm/dd/yyyy
3 = vbLongTime - Returns time: hh:mm:ss PM/AM
4 = vbShortTime - Return time: hh:mm
```

---

```
Dim Title,Input
Title = "format date"
Input = InputBox("Enter your date of Birthday !",Title,"10.02.20")
Input = FormatDateTime(Replace(Input,".","/"),1)
MsgBox Input
```

Comment: Using `FormatDateTime()` gives you very little control over to output format, this has been covered so many times but instead of flagging as a duplicate you still go ahead and answer. They aren’t even using correct syntax in the code example they posted.