# Format string based on current date and time

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I want to extract a file from SAP, however, I need the name of this file to be dynamic at the time of export, taking the time it was extracted.
For example, if it was extracted at 12:00, I need the name to be "12-00.XLSX"

````
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 142,25,false
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "zv15"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VKORG").text = "f86c"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VKBUR").text = "br01"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_MONTH-LOW").text = "1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_MONTH-HIGH").text = "12"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_MONTH-HIGH").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_MONTH-HIGH").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[4]/menu[11]").select
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtLAST_LOGON_TIME").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtLAST_LOGON_TIME").caretPosition = 8
session.findById("wnd[1]").close
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[43]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "11-50-30.XLSX"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").caretPosition = 8
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press```
````

Comment: I changed the title of your question as it seems it's only about formatting a string based on the current date and time. Please clarify if the question is about VBA or VBScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format current date and time in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574092/format-current-date-and-time-in-vbscript)

Answer (score -1):

In your example, you used the time from the previous login. I present an example of real system time.

e.G.

```
...   
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[4]/menu[11]").select
myTime = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtSYST-UZEIT").text
myName = replace(myTime, ":", "-") & ".xlsx"
session.findById("wnd[1]").close
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[43]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = myName
...
```

Regards, ScriptMan