# How to parse an ISO 8601 Timestamp in vbScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

The normal ASP/VBScript functions isDate and CDate can not handle ISO8601 formatted date strings. There are export functions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900045/vbscript-iso8601).

How do you convert these into a datetime value again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case someone falls in the same trap (`isDate('2010-08-12T00:00:00') = False`), I want to present my solution here.

You can use `isIsoDate` and `CIsoDate` like `isDate` and `CDate`, test cases below.

```
<% option explicit %>
<%
    ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function isIsoDate(s_input)
        dim obj_regex

        isIsoDate = false
        if len(s_input) > 9 then ' basic check before creating RegExp
            set obj_regex = new RegExp
            obj_regex.Pattern = "^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}(T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(Z|\+\d{4}|\-\d{4})?)?$"
            if obj_regex.Test(s_input) then
                on error resume next
                isIsoDate = not IsEmpty(CIsoDate(s_input))
                on error goto 0
            end if
            set obj_regex = nothing
        end if
    end function

    ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function CIsoDate(s_input)
        CIsoDate = CDate(replace(Mid(s_input, 1, 19) , "T", " "))
    end function



    ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' -- Testing
    ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    sub writeCheck(s_input)
        dim is_iso_date

        is_iso_date = isIsoDate(s_input)
        Response.Write "TEST: " & s_input & " = " & is_iso_date & vbNewline
        if is_iso_date then
            Response.Write "+ CONVERT: " & formatDateTime(CIsoDate(s_input)) & vbNewline
        end if
        Response.Write vbNewline
    end sub


    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    writeCheck "1234"
    writeCheck "2010-03-12"
    writeCheck "2010-03-12T12:34:56"
    writeCheck "2008-05-11T15:30:00Z"
    writeCheck "2010-99-12"
    writeCheck "2010-01-12T25:25:25"
%>
```

Script Output:

```
TEST: 1234 = False

TEST: 2010-03-12 = True
+ CONVERT: 12.03.2010

TEST: 2010-03-12T12:34:56 = True
+ CONVERT: 12.03.2010 12:34:56

TEST: 2008-05-11T15:30:00Z = True
+ CONVERT: 11.05.2008 15:30:00

TEST: 2010-99-12 = False

TEST: 2010-01-12T25:25:25 = False
```

Note: The conversion is quite basic, Time zone information is not taken into account.

Comment: that pattern matches with invalid dates something like `2010-99-12` or `2010-01-12T25:25:25`

Comment: @Kul-Tigin: Yeah, that's right. I improved the isDate function to reject such values. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: In case you are trying to parse `Date` from `*.xls` file here is extended RegExp pattern: `^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}(T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d{3})?(Z|\+\d{4}|\-\d{4})?)?$`